# SQL Query that includes an average of values from another query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Sorry my title isn't very descriptive but I am not sure how else to word it.

I have a query That includes month and year numbers for some reporting that needs to be done at the end of each month. It has a number of fields but the important ones for this question are: `qryReport`

```
MonthNumber | YearNumber | AverageRwkPercent 
1           | 2014       | This is the field I need help with
```

and another table: `tblRework`

```
Date    | percent   | include | void  |
1/3/14  | 98        | true    | false |
1/4/14  | 100       | false   | false |
1/6/14  | 95        | true    | true  |
1/7/14  | 100       | true    | false |
1/9/14  | 94        | true    | false |
...
```

What I want is for all of the percents where include is `True` and void is `False` for the 12 months before the `MonthNumber` and `YearNumber` for the record in `tblReport`

For this example I want to include from Jan 2013 to Jan 2014 the numbers 98, 100, and 94 and average them into the AverageRwkPercent column in `qryReport`

Is there a way to make an expression or subquery that will fill this for multiple records in `qryReport`?

It is worth noting I am working in Access 2010 but can work in SQL directly.

Thanks

Comment: how are these 2 tables related?

Comment: Also dont use special keywords such as Date as columns names

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: the tables here have slightly different names just to simplify my question and broaden its scope. The tables are not really related other than the date. I am doing rolling year reporting and need any value that is included and not void within the last 12 months to be averaged

Comment: My expected output for this example (which exludes all of the 2013 data to be included) is the average of 98, 100, and 94 which is 97.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful since access sql is a bit different from sql server sql. On the second one I would go with that:

```
SELECT AVG (percent), 
DATEPART (mm, Date),
DATEPART (yyyy, Date)
FROM tblRework
WHERE include=1
AND void=0
GROUP BY DATEPART (mm, Date)
, DATEPART (yyyy, Date)
```

By the way, if you want decimals you may need to do a casting before applying the `AVG` function.

Comment: +1 ...  Not access, but works assuming the database he is connecting to is MSSQL

Comment: this selects just that column from that table. This report query has many other columns from a few other tables.
`SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 From tbl1 RIGHT JOIN ON (YearNumber = Year(Date))`

Can the `Avg(percent), Month(date), Year(date)` and `WHERE` parts just be added in to their respective parts?

Comment: SO you have other information that is already grouped by month/year?  You'll want to use whats provided here as a subquery and join to it on month/year to get these avg values.  Your question doesn't seem to contain this component though